# Ratchet- PHP Websocket Deployment ISSUE

Tags: php, websocket, deployment, ratchet

My name is Dharmesh Pathar and I am a PHP developer.
I created and successfully ran a chat application in my local host using the Ratchet - PHP Websocket in PHP and Codeigniter both. Now I want to deploy it in the server.
Any one can help me? Thanks in advance.

I am working in the IT company, I can't do anything with the server without the information.

Comment: "Now I want to deploy it in the server. Any one can help me?" - What have you tried? What isn't working?